# How to search a large data with a boolean condition - Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, boolean, bigdata

I have a large table with 30M rows (increasing every day). The table includes some fields such as `id`, `stationId`, `sentAt` (dateTime), `isApproved` (tinyInt), ... I indexed column (`stationId`, `sentAt`).

Here is my query:

```
Select  id, stationId, sentAt, isApproved
    from  monitoring_data_info
    where  stationId = 'akhdsjha12'
      and  isApproved = 1
    order by  sentAt DESC
    limit  1
```

The database wastes a lot of time to return the result because it have to search to the whole dataset to compare with condition `isApproved` = 1. So my questions are:

- Should I index `isApproved` column which has 50% of 1?
- Is there any way to optiomize this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add this index:

```
ALTER TABLE monitoring_data_info
 ADD INDEX (stationId, isApproved, sentAt);
```

The order of columns in the index is important:

- The first two columns will reduce the search to only the matching rows.
- The third column will ensure the rows are read in the order you want to return them, so the ORDER BY will be a no-op.

You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or the [video of me presenting it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU). I explain how to optimize queries with indexes like this.

Comment: Thank you very much. You save my day! Your presentation is awesome. But I still wonder if I should have many indexes in a table or not. For example, I already had index_1 (stationId, isApproved, sentAt). But I have another query in my program such as `select id, stationId, sentAt from monitoring_data_info order by sentAt limit 1`. Should I add a new index like index_2 (sentAt) in the table? is it right if the index_1(stationId, isApproved, sentAt) is different from index_2(sentAt, stationId, isApproved)?  is it normal if a table have 10 different indexes?

Comment: Yes, you may need multiple indexes. Each index is used to optimize a different query. You can have a maximum of 64 indexes per table, but I rarely see a table that needs more than 8 or 10.

Comment: That one needs `INDEX(montering_data_info, sentAt)`.  See my [_Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: @RickJames, `monitoring_data_info` is the name of the table.

Comment: `INDEX(sentAt)` will be very useful.  Or any covering index that _starts with_ `sentAt`.

Comment: @BillKarwin, @RickJames For example, I already had a index as index_1 (stationId, isApproved, sentAt DESC) to optimize this query `select id, stationId, isApproved, sentAt from monitoring_data_info where stationId = 'shkjdhfk' and isApproved=1 order by sentAt DESC limit 1`. But another query is `select id, stationId, isApproved, sentAt from monitoring_data_info where stationId = 'shkjdhfk' and sentAt between (time1, time2) order by sentAt ASC`, so should I have another index like index2 (stationId, sentAt ASC)

Comment: @TinChip - Yes, you will need that second `INDEX`.